# How to export Scrapy's result to a specical JSON format?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, scrapy

I use Scrapy to crawl and scrap StackOverflow.com .
This is **so.py**

```
import scrapy

class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'link': response.url,
        }
```

Expected result: **so.json** (valid JSON format)

```
[
   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421917/exponential-number-in-custom-number-format-of-excel",
   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421343/can-not-install-requirements-txt",
   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418815/difference-between-two-approaches-to-pass-parameters-to-web-server",
   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421743/sharing-an-oracle-database-connection-between-simultaneous-celery-tasks",
   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421941/jquery-add-css-style",
]
```

Then run:

```
scrapy runspider so.py -o so.json
```

The result isn't like above expected. I stuck at here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `FEED_FORMAT=jsonlines` setting.

```
scrapy runspider so.py -o so.json --set FEED_FORMAT=jsonlines
```

If you want to get

```
[
   "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421917/exponential-number-in-custom-number-format-of-excel",
   "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421343/can-not-install-requirements-txt",
   "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418815/difference-between-two-approaches-to-pass-parameters-to-web-server",
   "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421743/sharing-an-oracle-database-connection-between-simultaneous-celery-tasks",
   "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421941/jquery-add-css-style",
]
```

you should write your own ItemExporter, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911162/scrapy-custom-exporter)

Comment: This is result after run the above command: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/7f75e0cf30ab0fe2ba79069ffa328b31 It still not like my expected result.

Comment: After apply your revised answer, I run command, then I have result: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/cc21a2a99b64fa367dbaec70f27b564c . It isn't expected result. Help me solve the problem!